# camel-jaxb 4.0 JAXBDataFormat class cannot access JAXBContext (Java 17)

Tags: spring, apache-camel, jaxb, dependency-management, java-17

Currently moving an application from Java 8 to Java 17. I understand that the [JAXB library has been deprecated and removed in the later versions of java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception). So I have tried to add the dependencies as shown in some of the solutions.

However, in the `camel-jaxb` depedency, there is a `JAXBDataFormat` class that makes use of JAXBContext. Because of this, compiling my code results in the error: `cannot access jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext` (which i have already imported). I have also tried to explicitly create the JAXBContext that will be used to create the JAXBDataFormat as shown in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751078/marshalling-with-jaxbdataformat-in-apache-camel), still the same issue.

I have also tried exluding the jakarta.xml depedency in camel but it still throws the same error. Is there a specific way or version i should be adding the new jaxb dependencies? Because the solution provided in the other link does not seem to be working for me.